# Whats the best way to read multiline input format to one record in spark?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, spark-csv

**Below is the input file(csv) looks like:**

Carrier_create_date,Message,REF_SHEET_CREATEDATE,7/1/2008
Carrier_create_time,Message,REF_SHEET_CREATETIME,8:53:57
Carrier_campaign,Analog,REF_SHEET_CAMPAIGN,25
Carrier_run_no,Analog,REF_SHEET_RUNNO,7

**Below is the list of columns each rows has:**
(Carrier_create_date, Carrier_create_time, Carrier_campaign, Carrier_run_no)

**Desired output as dataframe:**

7/1/2008,8:53:57,25,7

Basically the input file has column name and value on each rows.

**What I have tried so far is:**

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object coater4CR {

  // Define the application Name
  val AppName: String = "coater4CR"

  // Set the logging level.ERROR)
  Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // define the input parmeters
    val input_file = "/Users/gangadharkadam/myapps/NlrPraxair/src/main/resources/NLR_Praxair›2008›3QTR2008›Coater_4›C025007.csv"

    // Create the Spark configuration and the spark context
    println("Initializing the Spark Context...")

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(AppName).setMaster("local")

    // Define the Spark Context
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Read the csv file
    val inputRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(input_file)
      .flatMap(x => x._2.split(" "))
      .map(x => {
        val rowData = x.split("\n")

        var Carrier_create_date: String = ""
        var Carrier_create_time: String = ""
        var Carrier_campaign: String = ""
        var Carrier_run_no: String = ""

        for (data <- rowData) {
          if (data.trim().startsWith("Carrier_create_date")) {
            Carrier_create_date = data.split(",")(3)
          } else if (data.trim().startsWith("Carrier_create_time")) {
            Carrier_create_time = data.split(",")(3)
          } else if (data.trim().startsWith("Carrier_campaign")) {
            Carrier_campaign = data.split(",")(3)
          } else if (data.trim().startsWith("Carrier_run_no")) {
            Carrier_run_no = data.split(",")(3)
          }
        }
        (Carrier_create_date, Carrier_create_time, Carrier_campaign, Carrier_run_no)
      }).foreach(println)
  }
}
```

**issues with the above code**
when I run the above code I am  getting an empty list as below
(,,,)

**when I change**

Carrier_campaign = data.split(",")(3)

**to**

Carrier_campaign = data.split(",")(2)

I am getting the below output which is somewhat closer
(REF_SHEET_CREATEDATE,REF_SHEET_CREATETIME,REF_SHEET_CAMPAIGN,REF_SHEET_RUNNO)
(,,,)

some how the above code is not able to pick the last column position from the data row but is working for column positions 0,1,2.

**So my questions are-**

1. whats wrong with the above code
2. whats the efficient approach to read this multiline input and load it in tabular format to database

   Appreciate any help/pointers on this. Thanks.